# in Security Firstore Rules does it possible to only make users to read data depending on field value?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

for example in `Firstore` i have collection called `products` and every doc has  boolen field called `isAllow : false`

now in Security Firstore Rules How to make users can read only the docs with true value of `isAllow field` and the same with write .. i read the documentation  but couldn't understand exactly what i want

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

```
match /collection/{document} {
  allow read: if resource.data.isAllow == true;
}
```

Here [`resource.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document and the above rule will allow read operation only when isAllow field in the document being accessed is true.

Comment: thanks but in your code answer i can't see the collection name . or it will be public to all  collection ?

Comment: @Jack so it's `match /collectionName/{docId}` you can replace collectionName with whichever collection you want to follow this rule... else `match /{document=**}` will work for all collection..

Answer (score 2):

As Dharmaraj answered, you can allow only reading of those documents in security rules with:

```
match /products/{product} {
  allow read: if resource.data.isAllow == true;
}
```

But keep in mind that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters) on their own, and instead merely ensure the client doesn't try to read data it isn't permitted to. To meet the security rule above, you'll also need to use a query to read the allowed data:

```
firebase.firestore()
  .collection("products")
  .where("isAllow", "==", true)
```